# Почему  — шишка?

Tags: фразеология

Вдруг подумалось: а почему тех, кто занимает высокий пост, называют шишкой, а то и "большой шишкой"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому, что шишка "вскакивает". Примерно как человек "взлетает" на вершину.

Есть еще такое слово "шишак" (прямое родство с "шишкой" спорно) - средневековый шлем, увенчанный шарообразным украшением, также называемым "шишкой". Тут уж связь с высокопоставленным человеком просматривается "невооруженным взглядом".

Остальное - у Людмилы. С той оговоркой, что "шишка на ровном месте" чаще всего употребляется в ироническом значении. Т.е. вроде бы и шишка, но какая-то ненастоящая, деланная.

Comment: А почему шишка "большая", а не "высокая"?

Comment: Вот вы здавние увидели. Оно большое или высокое? Если не башня телевизионная, скорее всего первый эпитет будет "большой". Тоже и с шишкой. если на лбу вскочет, неужели скажете, что высокая?

Comment: шлемы с шишками носили высокопоставленные люди? в России?

Answer (score 2):

О них ещё говорят "шишка на ровном месте", т.е. то, что возвышается, находится НАД.Вот и важный человек находится НАД всеми остальными, только в переносном смысле.

Answer (score 2):

Заметьте называют не просто шишкой, а шишкой большой, противопоставляя шишкам маленьким. Это уже наводит на нехорошие мысли. Когда же в словаре Ушакова читаешь:

> **ШИШ** - Острая вершина чего-нибудь, торчок на чем-нибудь

Этимология становится в общих чертах понятна. Уж больно хорошо некоторые органы человеческого тела подходят под это описание.

В общем, *большая шишка* - это, если не вдаваться в излишние подробности, альфа-самец.

Answer (score 1):

"Большая шишка"

Помните картину "Бурлаки на Волге”, как на ней бурлаки тащат изо всех своих сил барку? Самое тяжелое и самое важное место в этой лямке — место первого бурлака. Он задает почин, он направляет остальных. Поэтому это место занимал самый сильный человек. Этого человека в бурлацкой лямке и называли "шишкой”. Вот и значит, что "большая шишка” — это большой и важный человек. 
Кстати по другой версии "большая шишка". Это пошло не от главаря бурлаков, а от шишака. Шлем такой был, шишаком назывался, носили обычно не ниже сотенного головы в войске. В бою ориентировались на большой шишак. От шишака название самой шишки (еловой, сосновой), т.к. она по форме как шишак, ну и главарей стали называть шишаками, шишками...Нашел в интернете.

Answer (score 0):

Калька с английского или французского: boss - начальник, это же слово означает "шишка" (фр.bosse).

P.S. Поражает фантазия отвечающих.